How do you split the variable number of function arguments into different groups?
I'm trying to do something like:
function get_data($query, $inputParams, &...$vars) {
    global $conn;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    if(!$stmt) {
        die("prep of query '" . $query . "' failed");
    }
    $stmt->bind_param($inputParams, ...$vars[0-strlen($inputParams)]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result(...$vars[strlen($inputParams)+1]);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}

Which would be used like:
get_data("SELECT x FROM table WHERE id=? AND y=?", "is", 839, $stringVariable, $outputVariable);

Where the "is" says the variables are an int and string and that because there's two of them, it means the first two elements of the variable number of arguments are the replacement parameters.
the ...$vars[0-strlen($inputParams)] is the range of the variable number of parameters from zero to the number of variables from the $inputParams length, and likewise with the ...$vars[strlen($inputParams)+1] trying to be everything from that position onwards.

To answer your question literally: we use arrays. get_data($sql, "is", [839, $stringVariable], $outputVariable); gets you your groups perfectly.

Speaking of your function, it's overnengienieered. Just use mysqli_execute_query instead of this piece of code, and call it a day.

I'm going to be brutally honest with you: this function is garbage. 1. Don't use globals. 2. Don't check for !$stmt. 3. Don't close the statement if it's the last thing you do in a function. 4. Use proper native param and return types. 5. Don't use bind_param and bind_result. 6. Don't pass $vars by reference; return the result instead. 7. $inputParams is just a nightmare parameter. It's the worst thing you could have done together with the variadic parameter. And you didn't even have to do it at all. You have really made it as tough for you as possible.

@Dharman okay. I'm new to PHP and have just been stabbing in the dark so I can get an idea to work. What's the better way to do what I'm doing?

You have been told that already: use mysqli_execute_query. $outputVariable = $conn->execute_query("SELECT x FROM table WHERE id=? AND y=?", [839, $stringVariable])->fetch_column(); read more on mysqli practical usage

Or at the very least pass the data in execute and use get_result if you need to support the older PHP version.

$vars is just an array, so you can slice it as usual:
$vars_param = array_slice($vars, 0, strlen($inputParams));
$vars_result = array_slice($vars, strlen($inputParams));

And pass them as usual:
$stmt->bind_param($inputParams, ...$vars_param);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result(...$vars_result);


This stuff is not enough because OP needs $outputVariable to be set. The most revolting way to code I've seen in my life

What do you mean this is not enough? The issue I am currently seeing is that it is not possible to directly pass 839, but $outputVariable can be set in this way.

It is not set yet. Anyway, your code answers to the question formulated in the title, hence it should be enough.

The real issue is that a literal like 839 can't be passed by reference.

it's easily fixable AND irrelevant to the "How do you split the variable number of function arguments" problem

@YourCommonSense The question explicitly gives an example with a literal, so it is relevant.

Not at all. We answer specific questions here. Which is "How do you split the variable number of function arguments", period. "I am passing a literal by reference" is another, completely different question that is absolutely irrelevant to the problem in question. And the OP is welcome to google their answer to this one

@YourCommonSense sorry my bad code offends you. I'm new to PHP and just using it for quick and dirty things. Feel free to tell me how to do it right.
